# Push Notification using Amazon SNS in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, xcode8

I am new to AWS SNS.I am trying to implement Amazon SNS push notification. I went through the documentation and perform all the APNS Prerequisite like:

iOS app registered with APNS

APNS SSL certificate

App private key

Device token

But problem is for sending notification document suggest that -
To send a notification to the iOS app on your device using the **Amazon SNS console**, see Using Amazon SNS Mobile Push.

To use the Amazon SNS API, see Send a push notification message to an iOS app using **Amazon SNS and APNS**.

I want to use Amazon SNS console to sent push notification, so how can use it and is it free?

Please guide me how can I do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679032/amazon-sns-push-notification-does-not-send-to-ios-application  If you are looking for a tutorial, I think this is not a good question.

Comment: May be @AitorPagán. Anyways thank you